# Socket Appliation throw a socketExpcetion in wan after a fixed time

Tags: c#

I have a socket application.

Server:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {

        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
        Socket server_socketListen = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
       
        IPAddress ips = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
        IPEndPoint ipNode = new IPEndPoint(ips, 9998);
        server_socketListen.Bind(ipNode);
        server_socketListen.Listen(10);
        Socket socket_commu = server_socketListen.Accept();
        while (true)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 1024];
          
            int num = socket_commu.Receive(buffer);

            string str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, num);
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + ":" + "data : " + str);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(480000);
         
            socket_commu.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("server：" + str));
        }
    }catch (Exception ex) 
    {
       
    }
}
```

Client:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Socket client_socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
   
    IPAddress ipAdress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
  
    IPEndPoint ipEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAdress, 9998);
  
    client_socket.Connect(ipEndpoint);
    while (true)
    {
        string rl = Console.ReadLine();
      
        client_socket.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rl.ToUpper()));

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 1024];
       
        int num = client_socket.Receive(buffer);
        string str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, num);
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + ":"+"data : " + str);
    }
}
```

I write "  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(480000);" in server, it's mean Server do something when receive client's data.

when ipAddress is '127.0.0.1' or lan ip, it's run and client get right server's response!

but if ipAddress is wan ip and set  sleep's time  is large time,such as 480000, and the server run in server computer with wan ip, and the client run in client compute, after a fixed time(maybe 240000), the server will throw a socketexception(errorcode:10060,msg: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond)!!

i think it's seem socket  server nerver timeout in lan, but if  in wan ,server will throw a socketexception after a fixed time value

can i adjust this time value?

Comment: Network hardware will often close long running connections if they have been inactive for a while - when running on LAN you probably are not going through any hardware that does this. Usually you'd periodically send ping/pong messages [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers#pings_and_pongs_the_heartbeat_of_websockets] to keep alive.

Comment: Some server limit a connection to a max time or max amount of data transferred.  You need to be an admin on server to change limits.

Comment: i guess somewhere can set this, but i can't find, such as registry . i think http be builded by tcpsocket, asp.net can set executionTimeout, so socket should can be setted.....

Comment: You need to offload the reading to a separate task or thread, so that it can continue buffering data into a concurrent queue or similar.